# field table is gone in laravel, how to fix it

Tags: php, laravel

i have already make table and field. buat when i opened again, the field is disappear. why?. please help me thanks[this is database tabel. but field is gone.][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUqq8.png[migration code][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ44w.png

Comment: please show us your migration code

Comment: Please don't show code in image format

Comment: that the migration code brother.

Comment: what field did disappear ? all fields in the migration are there

Comment: i already input name of hospital and address of hospitals, but my friend yesterday type php aritsan migrate:rollback

Answer (score 0):

@topan i saw your comment. "i mean. yesterday my friend type in my code editor, php aritsan:rollback and php artisan migrate:refresh, is that problem to my database? " .

answer is **yes**.

`php artisan migrate:rollback` will rollback the migrations by calling down method which will drop your table in this case.

`php artisan migrate:refresh` command will roll back all of your migrations and then execute the  migrate command. This command effectively re-creates your entire database.

so to migrate again run
`php artisan migrate`

see docs [Rolling back migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/migrations#rolling-back-migrations)

Comment: how to get back my database from php artisan migrate:refresh.? must i make a new databse again? thanks

Comment: run php artisan migrate

Comment: I have added that part to the answer too.so if it worked please remember to mark the answer as the correct answer.